# Citation with initals of authors

Tags: biblatex, biber

I use `biblatex` with `biber` and as style `alphabetic`

```
\usepackage[backend = biber, style=alphabetic ,maxnames=4,minnames=3,maxbibnames=99]%
  {biblatex}
```

At the moment, I get for all bibliography entries with more than 4 authors something like `[McW+07]` (first three letters of the family name of the first author) but I would like to get `[MBC+07]`. (`M`, `B` and `C` are the initials of the first three authors)

Is there a way to change my LaTeX code to solve my problem?

Comment: We really need a complete minimal example for this. Biber's label generation is much more complex and configurable than bibtex and it's likely just a settings issue but it's hard to guess without a MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a settings issue. If you look at the `ieee-alphabetic.cbx`, you'll see that all it does is set some options and then load `alphabetic`:

```
    \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
      maxalphanames = 4,
      maxcitenames  = 3,
      minalphanames = 3,
      minnames      = 1
    }
```

Label generation is done using `maxalphanames/minalphanames` and `maxnames/minnames` does not change this (because these are only enabled if the `labelalpha` option is true). So, you just need to set `maxalphanames=4` and `minalphanames=3` and you can use `alphabetic` as normal. See these options in the PDF doc.

You also might want to look at `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` as you can customise the format of labels quite a lot. As you've found out, this label generation interacts with the `maxalphanames/minalphanames` settings.

Comment: So, there is no bug in `biber`? Is it the normal behaviour?

Comment: There's no bug with `biber`, this is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that's my work around:

```
\usepackage[backend = biber,citestyle=ieee-alphabetic, bibstyle=alphabetic ,maxnames=4,minnames=3,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
```